# MOSFET H-bridge

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, 555, h-bridge

But I'm trying to build robust controller to reverse a motor in a harsh environment. The motor has built-in limit switches, which stop it from running-on at the end of it's stroke, which is fine for most applications, but I need there to be no power to the motor after it has finished it's activation, for two purposes:

1. in the event that the cable gets severed it will create a short (I am aware that if the cable gets severed and someone pushes the activation button it will still short, anyway)
2. if the limit switch fails, the motor will keep running, drawing current, and risking fire, or component failure.

To get around this I came up with an idea to use a 555 timer (actually a 556, but, semantics) whereby, a push of "button A" will cause the motor to run in one direction for "x seconds" and button B will do the opposite. I've made this adjustable with a potentiometer for tuning, but once I get it dialed in, I'll replace the pot with a fixed vaule resistor.

So at first I made the circuit using relays, no real problems, but it will be exposed to heavy vibration and unfavorable conditions, so I decided to make it solid state, and I googled and found many different schematics, and finally found an example that I though might work. I had most of the parts laying around, made a schematic, and now it keeps blowing fuses.

I checked the current across the fuse and found only 0.017 A at "idle" but with a fuse in, it blows the moment I apply power. I have checked the board everywhere, and there are no shorts, I've tested it a thousand times, and I cannot find a reason. so, I did the dumb thing and put an endmill (I just happened to have one on my desk) in place of the fuse, (I had an assumption, it was wrong), and I blew a MOSFET... it went bang.

Basic schematic below, the items circled in red were form one schematic online that I added to the schematic for the simple reason that I could omit them with no consequence if required, but I couldn't add them later if I needed to. the resistor values are all just figures from online schematics, I've been playing around with resistor values, everything works 100% perfect until the FETs. I used the IRF540/IRF9540N only because I had them available, but when I've looked at other schematics, and compare their fets on paper, they are very similar. The circuit only needs to draw about 1.7 A (2.5 MAX) @ 12 V DC and less at higher voltages.

[image]

When I power up the circuit without the FETs, everything works, all the right voltages/resistances in all the right places, perfect. but when I put the FETs in the system, kaboom...

Comment: most likely cause is both the top and bottom MOSFETs conduct at the same time, shorting the power supply

Comment: Your schematic is upside down and has wires running through components. It might make sense to you, but I have trouble interpreting it. You’ve also used the wrong symbol for a standard resistor. Apart from that, possible problems are many and varied.  If you consider every piece of wire is a resistor, follow where the current flows and calculate the voltage drop. Ensure high current paths don’t run through low current circuitry. To simplify the circuit, you could use a dpdt relay to reverse the motor and use one mosfet for pwm speed control.

Comment: Hi Kartman, Thanks, the first iteration was with relays and it worked fine, but because this is used in a very rough environment, and relays often fail in this environment due to the vibrations and shock loading, I'm trying to make it solid state. the schematic tarted off nice and clean, but as I added different stuff it became quite messy, I will clean it up once I get eh circuit working. the resistor symbols are from the program parts library, I'm not too concerned with that, at the moment it's just through hole resistors, but eventually once I get it working, it will all be surface mount.

Comment: Thanks user253751 any ideas on how to fix that? I found many, many schematics online with the same or very similar layout. as far as I can tell, the only real difference is the actual mosfets used, but when I searched the data sheets, they're very similarly spec'd, with max current being the only major difference.

Comment: If Q3 and Q4 are off, all 4 MOSFETs are conducting because each FET "sees" Vgs of 6 V.

Comment: Thank Jens, can you tell me how to fix it?